# Not able to locate the element using XPath locator for Edge Driver instance of Selenium 2.47.1

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

Getting following exception Message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: ????tor not implemented (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 16 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 02:56:46'
System info: host: 'WIN-CMEFNAVR643', ip: '192.168.3.254', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
Capabilities [{acceptSslCerts=true, browserVersion=20.10240.16384.0, platformVersion=10, browserName=MicrosoftEdge, takesScreenshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, takesElementScreenshot=true, platformName=windows, platform=ANY}]
Session ID: 65DB54C4-7689-4443-A6C7-DD95943B38B8
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//input[@id='username']}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:445)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:358)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:340)
    at edge_demo.Test.main(Test.java:26)
```

Selenium 2.47.1 doesn't have support for edge driver instace to locate element using xpath???
Kindly request you to provide solution for this?

Comment: only xpath not working or other properties as well

Answer (score 7):

Finding elements by XPath isn't supported in the initial release of the Microsoft Edge driver implementation. Unfortunately, there is no documentation on that limitation; it is derived from experimentation and private discussions with members of the Microsoft Edge development team. It is intended to be implemented in an updated release, but of course, no timetable can be specified for that update.

Comment: Thank you Jim for valuable input.

Answer (score 2):

Support for location elements using XPath was added in build 10547 and available in the November public release version 25 (build 10586, EdgeHTML version 13).

See the [WebDriver Status](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/webdriver/details/) page to see status of automation features in Microsoft Edge.  There are still a number of features that are not implemented that can bite you.